# Haskell: Print elements of a list

Tags: haskell

I have a list
`let a = [1,2,3,4]`

I want to extract 2 elements at a time to perform computation. Can anyone tell me how this can be achieved? I am new to Haskell.

I am aware of `take 2 a`. But how can I put this in a loop so that 2 elements are extracted at a time. I am confused.

Comment: Have a look at the [`splitAt`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:splitAt) function or [`chunksOf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.3.1/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v:chunksOf)

Comment: Thanks.. But then how should I loop through the tuples to perform calculations??

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example. You are (or should become) familiar with the `map` function:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f [] = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

Here, you might have a function that takes *two* arguments, and want to apply it to two elements from a list at a time. Here's a function `mapTwo` that behaves like `map`, but with a two-argument function. For simplicity, we'll assume the list has an even number of elements.

```
mapTwo :: (a -> a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
mapTwo f [] = []
mapTwo f (x1:x2:xs) = f x1 x2 : mapTwo f xs
```

Comment: Shouldn't tgere be a case for `mapTwo [x] = error "singleton lists are not allowed"`?

Comment: See my last sentence. I just didn't want to get into how to handle a list with an odd number of values.

Comment: Rather, I didn't want to bring up pros and cons of partial functions, using `Maybe` or `Either`, raising an error, or using an exception monad.

Comment: I'm not getting how to use `mapTwo`.

Answer (score 4):

You can write your own recursive function and pattern-match on elements you are interested in:

```
f (a:b:list) = doSomeThingWith a b : f list
```

Make sure to properly match on `[]` and `[a]` cases.